# Как вывести все значения JSON

Tags: python, json, list

Вообщем получаю запрос в JSON, где есть несколько значений message у которых есть title, но я смог вывести только самое первое(, помогите пожалуйста как вывести все которые там есть?

```
kek = ""
chatik = await self.api.messages.getDialogs(count=20)
for i in chatik:
    kek += f"{i['items'][0]['message']['title']}"

return await msg.answer(kek)


"response": {
"items": [{
"message": {
"title": "nazvanie1"
},
"message": {
 "title": "nazvanie2"
}
}]
```

Мне нужно получить все названия во всех message. что бы вывело допустим nazvanie1, nazvanie2

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример входных данных (JSON) и то, что хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: Сейчас секунду.

Comment: Готово, надеюсь поймете

Comment: в цикле должно добавлять каждое название каждого блока message, но добавляет толькое первое, не знаю как правильно выразится :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для словаря:

```
In [46]: d
Out[46]:
{'response': {'items': [{'message': {'title': 'nazvanie1'}},
   {'message': {'title': 'nazvanie2'}}]}}
```

решение:

```
In [47]: [x['message']['title'] for x in d['response']['items']]
Out[47]: ['nazvanie1', 'nazvanie2']
```

**UPDATE:**

> нужно что бы после каждого названия начиналась новая строка nazvani1
>   \n nazvani2

```
In [75]: res = '\n'.join([x['message']['title'] for x in d['response']['items']])

In [76]: print(res)
nazvanie1
nazvanie2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, именно то что нужно

Comment: Если вам не трудно можете сделать, что бы каждое название с новой строки было, в решении :3

Comment: @user293323, укажите в вопросе то, что хотите получить на выходе... Это должна быть строка/список/что-то ещё?

Comment: строка, сейчас выводит все в 1 строку, нужно что бы после каждого названия начиналась новая строка
nazvani1 \n
nazvani2, попытался сделать, но не вышло(

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, извините что так плохо объясняю, всего наилучшего)